# Gunicorn Worker timeout while using any firestore function - not even a get

Tags: python, google-app-engine, websocket, google-cloud-firestore, gunicorn

I'm having a lot of trouble to deal with Cloud Firestore in native mode. I'm used to work with NDB, but tried to change my app to Flexible Environment, since I need to work with websocket. But, I'm really having a nightmare to use Firestore. I had to use Tasks API to do a simple batch commit, that worked well. But I can't retrieve a single document from database, neither locally or deployed. Locally, I keep getting:

```
[2019-08-31 20:05:17 -0300] [1951] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1951
[2019-08-31 20:05:47 -0300] [1927] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1951)
[2019-08-31 20:05:48 -0300] [1964] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1964
[2019-08-31 20:06:18 -0300] [1927] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1964)
[2019-08-31 20:06:19 -0300] [1977] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1977
```

I have a collection called Contacts with a document called 5599999999 with a pair of values: "name":"test". Also, I'm running locally with gunicorn, since I need websockets.

This is the command to run locally:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080 -k flask_sockets.worker  main:app --reload
```

And my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -k flask_sockets.worker main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

main.py

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import asyncio
import google.cloud.exceptions
import firebase_admin
from google.cloud import firestore
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sockets import Sockets

cred = credentials.Certificate('service.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():

  teste = GetContacts()

  return str(teste.to_dict())

def GetContacts():
  db = firestore.client()
  contacts = db.collection(u'Contacts').document(u'5599999999').get()
  return contacts
```

I simply expect the output of this to be the pair of values. But it get's running indefinitely...

Tried now, with only Flask. Runs smoothly. No problems at all and real fast. But, I'm also getting this kind of error, besides getting the pair of values:

```
$ python main.py
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 325-288-398
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2019 01:03:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR:root:An error occurred during a request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sockets.py", line 40, in __call__
    handler, values = adapter.match()
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1799, in match
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1791, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1774, in raise_routing_exception
    raise request.routing_exception
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 336, in match_request
    self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)
  File "/Users/dr/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1799, in match
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2019 01:03:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2019 01:03:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: The error from your test without Gunicorn seems like something related to the websockets. To check if it is a high latency issue, or if the app is not able through the websockets, could you try increasing the timeout of Gunicorn? Like in the following command: `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080 -t 120 -k flask_sockets.worker  main:app --reload`

Answer (score 9):

This is related to `gevent` (used by `flask_sockets`) and `grpc` (used by firebase) conflict described in this issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4629 the solution is to add the following code

```py
import grpc.experimental.gevent as grpc_gevent
grpc_gevent.init_gevent()
```

Comment: I can't upvote this enough! Absolute lifesaver for a problem that took forever to diagnose!

Comment: I serious can't believe that my appengine flask launch was conflicting with my firebase set key-value command.  This 502 failure was an unbelievable pain.  I mean can't Google just give a basic image for launching a web view with persistent storage.  Good find!

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn's default timeout setting is 30 seconds, which is consistent with what I'm seeing in your logs. I don't think this is a gunicorn issue. Have you tried making the connection without gunicorn?

Comment: Actually, I don't remember. I'll try it. But, to run websockets, Google suggests to use gunicorn, right?

Comment: Updated the question with the connection without gunicorn.